# How to setup post-commit hook for teamcity in Git using Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, teamcity-9.0

I am trying to setup Git post-commit hook for a particular project in Teamcity to trigger the builds if there is a change in BitBucket repository.

I am trying to use the following powershell script:

```
curl --user username:password -X POST "http://teamcity.org.com/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=project:(id:project_id)"
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
No VCS roots are found for locator 'project:(id:project_id)' with current user 'teamcityuser' (TeamCityUser) {id=1672}. Check
 locator and permissions using '/app/rest/vcs-root-instances?locator=$help' URL.
```

Is there any other way to configure post-commit  hook in Git for teamcity using powershell script?

Comment: This isn't powershell.  That's a bash utility and you aren't passing any body in your POST

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes it is. I am using `curl` utility inside a Powershell script. I am not passing anything in the body that's a different thing.

Comment: Get a copy of `showargs.exe` (see [Windows IT Pro - Running Executables in PowerShell](http://beta.itprotoday.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell)) and you can inspect how PowerShell is parsing the `curl` command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project is not a valid locator ID, so you may need to consider changing the URL that you are curling.

From the TeamCity Documentation, the acceptable locators are as follows:

> 1. type:VCS root type - VCS root instances of the specified version control (e.g. "jetbrains.git", "mercurial", "svn")
> 2. vcsRoot:( vcsRootLocator) - VCS root instances corresponding to the VCS root matched by "vcsRootLocator"
> 3. buildType:(buildTypeLocator) - VCS root instances attached to the matching build configuration
> 4. property:(name:name,value:value,matchType:matching) - VCS root instances with the property of name "name" and value matching condition "matchType" (e.g. equals, contains) by the value "value".

You may be able to get away with structuring your api request to query for the project ID like so:

```
curl --user username:password -X POST "http://teamcity.org.com/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=property:(name:project,id:project_id,matchtype:contains)"
```